# how to change bootstrap class col-md-10 into col-md-12 of div using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I used thumbnail section and view section in my project. So I divided parent div into two div, first is **col-md-3**(that is thumbnail div) and second is **col-md-9**(that is view section). Now I want to hide first div and change second div into **col-md-12** for small device like mobile or ipad.

Is there any way to make it with media query?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far, and refer to the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#responsive-classes). The breakpoints are already used by the Bootstrap grid classes so there's no reason to add a custom media query.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap col system for grid has this built in.
When you specify col-md-3 you are saying "at medium screen give this col 3 blocks".
You can also do, side by side col-sm-12 to give it the entire row when on large screen and col-sm-0 to hide it when on smaller screens.
Look here for a better explanation about bootstrap grid system:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">THUMBNAIL</div>
  <div class="col-md-9">Some data</div>
</div>
```

This will solve your issue.
For extra small and small screen thumbnail will not appear.

Comment: @Durgesh Gupta, You are new to stackoverflow. If answer is correct then check as right answer and upvote

Comment: thumbnail hide by class="col-md-3 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block" but my view section still at col-md-9. So what should i do for that?

Comment: Use like this,  <div class="col-md-9 col-12"></div>